# Power BI : How to Filter a table based on the most recent date

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

New to Power BI - this sounds like a simple question but I have note been able to resolve. I have a data table below called 'Table'

No      Date        Type    Name
44456   18/12/2018  1   AIB
44456   22/06/2007  0   Outlook
44456   18/12/2018  2   Orange
44456   18/01/2018  3   John
44460   30/03/2007  0   Outlook
44460   19/09/2014  3   Frank
44460   19/09/2014  2   Apple
44460   19/04/2021  0   Gmail
44460   19/04/2021  1   BOI
44452   16/11/2006  0   Outlook
44452   16/01/2007  1   KBC
44452   19/09/2014  3   Tom
44452   19/09/2014  2   Melon
44452   18/10/2015  2   Banana

I need to get this table to appear as below:

```
| Asset No  | Transfer Date     | Transfer Type     | Owners Name   | 0     | 1     | 2     | 3     |
|---------- |---------------    |---------------    |-------------  |---    |---    |---    |---    |
| 44456     | 18/12/2018        | 1                 | AIB           | 0     | 1     | 0     | 0     |
| 44456     | 22/06/2007        | 0                 | Outlook       | 1     | 0     | 0     | 0     |
| 44456     | 18/12/2018        | 2                 | Orange        | 0     | 0     | 1     | 0     |
| 44456     | 18/01/2018        | 3                 | John          | 0     | 0     | 0     | 1     |
| 44460     | 30/03/2007        | 0                 | Outlook       | 0     | 0     | 0     | 0     |
| 44460     | 19/09/2014        | 3                 | Frank         | 0     | 0     | 0     | 1     |
| 44460     | 19/09/2014        | 2                 | Apple         | 0     | 0     | 1     | 0     |
| 44460     | 19/04/2021        | 0                 | Gmail         | 1     | 0     | 0     | 0     |
| 44460     | 19/04/2021        | 1                 | BOI           | 0     | 1     | 0     | 0     |
| 44452     | 16/11/2006        | 0                 | Outlook       | 1     | 0     | 0     | 0     |
| 44452     | 16/01/2007        | 1                 | KBC           | 0     | 1     | 0     | 0     |
| 44452     | 19/09/2014        | 3                 | Tom           | 0     | 0     | 0     | 1     |
| 44452     | 19/09/2014        | 2                 | Melon         | 0     | 0     | 0     | 0     |
| 44452     | 18/10/2015        | 2                 | Banana        | 0     | 0     | 1     | 0     |
```

That is, I want to look at my "No" column and then look at the "Type". I want the current type to be represented by 1 and irrelevant data to be represented by 0. I want the current type, ie. based on the most recent date to be the deciding factor.

I have used the below calculated column:

Is Latest Row Filter = VAR LatestDate = MAXX(FILTER('Table',[No] = EARLIER([No])),[Date])
RETURN IF([Date]=LatestDate,1,0)

But this excludes all duplicate types, ie. if there are x2 0's in type both return 0 rather than show 1 as the most recent 0 type.

Separately, I also tested the Custom Column in Power Query Editor:

if [Type] = 0 then
if [Date] = List.Max(let currentOwner = [No]     in Table.SelectRows(#"Sorted Rows",
each [No] = currentOwner)[Date])
then 1
else 0
else 0

This only worked on duplicated, ie. the opposite to the above.

Can alone please assist in providing x4 Custom Column formulae for Power Query Editor that I can use for each of the 4 types and to provide a 1 to show the most recent date and a 0 to show the older dates or irrelevant data?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Group by No and Type
- Create a custom aggregation to create the rows, filling in the `0,1,2,3` columns as appropriate
- Re-expand the list of records

***M Code***

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table32"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"No", Int64.Type}, {"Date", type date}, {"Type", Int64.Type}, {"Name", type text}}),
    
//add Index column for final sorting
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),

//Group by No and Type
//Custom aggregation to create a row for each No/Type
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Index", {"No","Type"}, {
        {"typeCols", (t)=> List.Generate(
            ()=>[0=if t[Date]{0} = List.Max(t[Date]) and t[Type]{0} = 0 then 1 else 0,
                1=if t[Date]{0} = List.Max(t[Date]) and t[Type]{0} = 1 then 1 else 0,
                2=if t[Date]{0} = List.Max(t[Date]) and t[Type]{0} = 2 then 1 else 0,
                3=if t[Date]{0} = List.Max(t[Date]) and t[Type]{0} = 3 then 1 else 0,
                idx = 0],
            each [idx] <Table.RowCount(t),
            each [0=if t[Date]{[idx]+1} = List.Max(t[Date]) and t[Type]{[idx]+1} = 0 then 1 else 0,
                1=if t[Date]{[idx]+1} = List.Max(t[Date]) and t[Type]{[idx]+1} = 1 then 1 else 0,
                2=if t[Date]{[idx]+1} = List.Max(t[Date]) and t[Type]{[idx]+1} = 2 then 1 else 0,
                3=if t[Date]{[idx]+1} = List.Max(t[Date]) and t[Type]{[idx]+1} = 3 then 1 else 0,
                idx = [idx]+1],
            each 
              t{[idx]} & [[0],[1],[2],[3]])}
    
        }),

//Remove unneeded columns
//and expand the aggregation
//rename the columns
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"No", "Type"}),
    #"Expanded typeCols" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Removed Columns", "typeCols"),
    #"Expanded typeCols1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded typeCols", "typeCols", 
        {"No", "Date", "Type", "Name", "Index", "0", "1", "2", "3"}, 
        {"Asset No", "Transfer Date", "Transfer Type", "Owners Name", "Index", "0", "1", "2", "3"}),

//set data types
    types = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded typeCols1",
        List.Zip({Table.ColumnNames(#"Expanded typeCols1"),
                    {Int64.Type, type date,Int64.Type, type text, Int64.Type,Int64.Type,Int64.Type,Int64.Type,Int64.Type}})),

//resort back to original order and remove the index column
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(types,{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"
```

[image]